# Is there a way to programatically switch to hashHistory from browserHistory when on a webpack dev server?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

Is there a way to automatically switch to hashHistory from browserHistory in React Router when using the webpack-dev-server? I frequently get the cannot GET/*routename* error if the page refreshes. I can get around this issue by manually switching over to hashHistory, but I'm wondering if there is a good way to automatically switch this back and forth depending on whether I am in development or production.

my webpack.prod.config.js

```
const config = require('./webpack.config.js');
const webpack = require('webpack');

config.plugins.push(
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    "process.env": {
      "NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify("production")
    }
  })
);

config.plugins.push(
  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    compress: {
      warnings: false
    }
  })
);

module.exports = config;
```

My Router

```
render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    {/** ###### HOME ROUTE ###### */}
    <Route path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/company" component={Company} />
    <Route path="/help" component={Help} />
    <Route path="/features" component={Features} />
    <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
    <Route path="/work" component={Work} />
    {/** ###### END HOME ROUTES ###### */}
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check your NODE_ENV variable before you set your history, something like this

```
import { Router, Route, browserHistory,hashHistory IndexRoute } from 'react-router'

let history = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? browserHistory : hashHistory;


render((
  <Router history={history}>
    {/** ###### HOME ROUTE ###### */}
    <Route path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/company" component={Company} />
    <Route path="/help" component={Help} />
    <Route path="/features" component={Features} />
    <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
    <Route path="/work" component={Work} />
    {/** ###### END HOME ROUTES ###### */}
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```